# Is .NET Core 2.0 logging broken?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I can't seem to get Trace level log information outputted after upgrading to .NET Core 2.0 (+ASP.NET Core 2.0).

In fact, if I do a `dotnet new web`project and add the code below in Startup for Configure, I do not get any trace or debug log messages, but I get the Information and Error messages twice. Commenting out the `.AddConsole()`call will output these (Information and Error) only once - suggesting that it gets configured automatically with a console provider by default. Keep in mind, this is a "File -> New" project experience, there is nothing setup in `Program.cs` for logging or configuration at all for this - except for what I've added. Anyone seen things? Or should I register a GitHub issue for it.

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    loggerFactory.AddConsole(Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LogLevel.Trace);

    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }

    app.Run(async (context) =>
    {
        var logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger("Blah");
        logger.LogTrace("Hello world : Trace");
        logger.LogDebug("Hello world : Debug");
        logger.LogInformation("Hello world : Information");
        logger.LogError("Hello world : Error");

        await context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello World!");
    });
}
```

Comment: `will give me them once` What do you mean by that?

Comment: Edited; I get Info and Error twice - but if I take out my AddConsole() line - I get the Info and Error once - but no Trace nor Debug messages at all with our without my explicit line to say console and Trace level.

Comment: Are you running in development? Default environment now is Production.. you can try `set ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development; dotnet run`

Comment: I ran into a similar issue. Adding a `await Task.Delay(1)` after the logging statements gets the Console to display logs. If It take it out, only partial logs are displayed on the Console.  The accepted answer doesn't actually do anything. It seems to be a threading issue.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The way logging is configured has changed a little... The recommended way (and it's pretty well documented in [this GitHub issue/announcement](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/255) to do it now is to configure the loggers on the `AddLogging` method, such as

```
services.AddLogging(builder =>
{
    builder.AddConfiguration(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"))
        .AddConsole()
        .AddDebug();
});
```

And have an `appsettings.json` like

#### Notice

Seems a few people are confused, because the example only demonstrates the configuration of `Console` provider and not all loggers.

The `LogLevel` section configures logging level for all namespaces (`Default` key) or for a specific namespace (`System` overrides the default value for all classes logging whose namespace starts with `System.*`.

This is for the class used in `T` in `ILogger<T>`). This allows to set a higher or lower than default logging level for loggers from this namespace.

```
{
  "ApplicationInsights": {
    "InstrumentationKey": ""
  },
  "Logging": {
    "IncludeScopes": false,
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "System": "Warning",
      "Microsoft": "Information"
    },
    "Console": {
      "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "Warning",
        "System": "Information",
        "Microsoft": "Information"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Please note that the structure of the appsettings.json changed from what it used to be in .NET Core 1.x and that `Logging` entry in the `appsettings.json` now has logger provider names in it, which allows you to configure logging levels per logging provider.

Previously, the entry in `appsettings.json` would only be applicable to the console logger.

Alternatively, the logging can now be moved within the `WebHostBuilder` instead.

```
public static void Main()
{
    var host = new WebHostBuilder()
        .UseKestrel()
        .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
        .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) =>
        {
            var env = hostingContext.HostingEnvironment;

            config.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
                .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
                .AddJsonFile("hosting.json", optional: false)
                .AddEnvironmentVariables();
        })
        .ConfigureLogging((webhostContext, builder) => {
            builder.AddConfiguration(webhostContext.Configuration.GetSection("Logging"))
            .AddConsole()
            .AddDebug();
        })
        .UseIISIntegration()
        .UseStartup<Startup>()
        .UseApplicationInsights()
        .Build();

    host.Run();
}
```

#### Update

In case one doesn't want to use the `appsettings.json`, one can register the filters in code too.

```
services.AddLogging(builder =>
{
    builder.AddConfiguration(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"))
        // filter for all providers
        .AddFilter("System", LogLevel.Debug)
        // Only for Debug logger, using the provider type or it's alias
        .AddFilter("Debug", "System", LogLevel.Information)
        // Only for Console logger by provider type
        .AddFilter<DebugLoggerProvider>("System", LogLevel.Error)
        .AddConsole()
        .AddDebug();
});
```

Comment: Thanks.. In fact, just adding an `appsettings.json` file with the Logging configuration without any logging setup at all seems to give me what I need.

Comment: or just `builder.SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Trace);`

Comment: Note that using `AddConfiguration` requires the `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration` package.

Comment: Does any of this enable actual debug messages to be written to the log? That is with "LogLevel Default: Debug" the output of Debug.WriteLine ends up in the log. Because if not it's not much use, because 1) I don't want to have to inject Microsoft's logging class into every single low level component in my app and replace every single WriteLine with _log.LogDebug, 2) If I'm using a third party component I may not be able to inject Microsoft's logging class into these components.

Comment: @Neutrino: `Debug.WriteLog` isn't really meant for application level logging, its there for develop-time logging (which is the reasons it by default only logs to the Debug output window). For app-level logging you were always supposed to use an proper logging library. And there aren't many 3rd party libraries which use `Debug.WriteLine` and even if, `Debug.WriteLine` has a conditonal operator and **is not** compiled to release builds, check the [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7821bed5(v=vs.110).aspx#Syntax).

Comment: I found your example of `appsettings.json` to be incorrect for .NET Core 2.1, this one worked for me https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-2.1

Comment: @Art: May explain what it doesn't work? (other than that the `LogLevel` section may be missing, which sets the default logging level for **all** loggers, though the Console Logger was the one asked in the question). Also feel free to suggest an edit :)

Comment: @Tseng with the logging config from the example above I could not get the Info messages logged. See my answer below in this thread with the example that worked for me.

Comment: @Art: But that wasn't really a requirement of the question. The OP asked why his logging didn't work after upgrading and the answer was because the structure and way of configuring logging has changed. Before the parameter less constructor would set the default for all loggers. Now its taken either from the new appsettings.json structure or from the per-logger provider configuration entry (above sample for `Console`. How to configure it for your requirement wasn't part of the question. The `Default` one sets it for all namespaces, the `Microsoft` overrides it for all `Microsoft.*` namespaces

Comment: This way you can set fine grained control over logging, i.e. have `Information` or lower for `Default`, and set `Trace` level etc. for a specific namespace you want to have logged/traced in detail. Why I asked was, because the above does works, but maybe not as you expect it, since only demonstrated how to setup console logger, not **every** logger

Comment: Incase it helps anyone, adding the following `builder.ConfigureLogging((hostContext, logging) => { logging.AddConfiguration(hostContext.Configuration.GetSection("Logging")); });` helped resolve my `appSettings.json` file being ignored as suggested by @Tseng. Performed on the `IWebHostBuilder`.

Answer (score 9):

I spent almost twenty minutes to realize that since `Configuration.GetSection("Logging")` in the *Startup.cs* file reads the section `"Logging"` from the config in the *appsettings.json* file, which was configured as `"Error"`. Changing it to `"Information"` or anything lower, fixed the issue.

Here's what the *appsettinsg.json* file looks now:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "IncludeScopes": true,
    "Debug": {
      "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "Information"
      }
    },
    "Console": {
      "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "Information"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

To find out more about the levels of logging (such as in `"Information"`), check out [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?tabs=aspnetcore2x#log-level) link, that also provides general information on ASP.NET Core logging.

I'm just posting here, just in case you bump into any trouble with getting the logging to work, make sure you've been through that JSON file.

Answer (score 6):

Nothing of the above works for me
The only workaround was to write a method

```
private void ConfigLogging( ILoggingBuilder builder ) {
    builder.SetMinimumLevel( LogLevel.Trace );
    //... additional configuration...
}
```

and when using the AddLogging extension method write it as

```
services.AddLogging( ConfigLogging );
```

Comment: You sure your appsettings.json had the correct format? Or if the value was overriden by one of the other config sources (developing settings, environment variables etc)?

Comment: I solved it by adding this line:
`.ConfigureLogging((hostingContext, logging) =>
{
    ...
    logging.AddConfiguration(hostingContext.Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
    ...
})
`

Comment: It's almost as if "Trace" is treated specially and will only be honored as a log level if in the declared code and NOT the config file. But I see no documentation of that.

Answer (score 0):

The following structure of `appsettings.json` seems to work fine:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "System": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Information"
    },
    "Console":
    {
      "IncludeScopes": true
    }
  }
}
```

Taken from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-2.1

Also, see what your start up calls are, I find the following works for me:

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
    {

        var logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                .MinimumLevel.Information()
                .WriteTo.Sink(jsonSink)
                .Enrich.WithExceptionDetails()
                .CreateLogger();

        Log.Logger = logger;
    }
}
```