# Can't set ASP.NET Core console logging below Information

Tags: c#, asp.net, logging, asp.net-core

I can't seem to get any Debug or Trace statements displayed in console.

In `Startup.cs` `Configure(...)` I have:

```
loggerFactory
    .WithFilter(
        new FilterLoggerSettings
        {
            {"AssetTrader", LogLevel.Debug},
            {"Microsoft", LogLevel.Warning},
            {"System", LogLevel.Warning},
        })
    .AddConsole();
```

In the controller action I have:

```
this._logger.LogTrace("Trace");
this._logger.LogDebug("Debug");
this._logger.LogInformation("Info");
this._logger.LogWarning("Warn");
```

But the console output only shows the two entries:

```
info: AssetTrader.Controllers.HomeController[0]
  Info
warn: AssetTrader.Controllers.HomeController[0]
  Warn
```

I have also tried simply `loggerFactory.AddConsole(LogLevel.Debug)`, same result.

Gist of a simple test project to reproduce the issue: https://gist.github.com/modo-lv/66e3209f89e986423397928630ba5f9a

Comment: Maybe you got overwritten by appsettings.json logging configuration?

Comment: Not using appsettings.json (yet).

Comment: Do you use asp.net core 2.0? Could you put your code on github or gist? Or more code here?

Comment: @nemke Added gist URL.

Comment: Please check out my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45782021/455493). The way logging is registered has changed a bit in ASP.NET Core 2.0

Comment: I think it should work when you use `.AddFilter<T>()` or `.AddFilter("Namesapce", debugLevel)` as pointed in the announcement: https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/255 or `.AddFilter("Console", "Namespace", debugLevel)` overload

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved, thanks to [Tseng](http:///users/455493/tseng)'s comment and answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45782021/455493).

In my case, removing

```
loggerFactory
    .WithFilter(
        new FilterLoggerSettings
        {
            {"AssetTrader", LogLevel.Debug},
            {"Microsoft", LogLevel.Warning},
            {"System", LogLevel.Warning},
        })
    .AddConsole();
```

from `Configuration(..)` and adding

```
services.AddLogging(
    builder =>
    {
        builder.AddFilter("AssetTrader", LogLevel.Debug)
            .AddFilter("Microsoft", LogLevel.Warning)
            .AddFilter("System", LogLevel.Warning)
            .AddConsole();
    });
```

to `ConfigureServices(...)` solved the problem.

Comment: Yes, that is ASP.NET Core 2.0 thing