# Logging changes between .NET Core 1 (project.json) and .NET Core 2 regarding serilog

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, serilog

We have a project that's using the old .NET Core `project.json` format. It has a custom logging library that's injected through DI, but it's not well written (!) and (I think) it even has some overrides in DI for logging interfaces.

However, as bad as this implementation of logging is, I was able to add serilog to that project, I could see logs for requests coming in, and I just needed to inject `ILogger` to my controllers and see their logs, but after upgrading that project to .NET Core 2, it seems that the whole logging pipeline is broken, and adding serilog doesn't seem to have any effect.

I know that it's impossible to know what's exactly happening without knowing the exact implementation details, but I was hoping to get some insight about logging changes between the two .NET Core versions, and what *may* be causing the issue

Thank you in advance

This is a screenshot when using `ColoredConsole` in serilog in project.json when doing a single call to a controller:
[image]
What I do in this project:

1. In my `Startup` class's constructor (`SerilogLoggerConfiguration` is an alias to `Serilog.LoggerConfiguration` because the custom logging project also has a `LoggerConfiguration` class!!):

   ```
   Log.Logger = new SerilogLoggerConfiguration()  
       .Enrich.FromLogContext()  
       .WriteTo.ColoredConsole()  
       .CreateLogger();
   ```
2. In `Configure` method:

   ```
   loggerFactory.AddSerilog();
   ```

And this is a screenshot in new project (using the `README` in `serilog-aspnetcore` to setup serilog):
[image]

What I do in this project:

1. In my `Main` method:

   ```
   Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
       .Enrich.FromLogContext()
       .WriteTo.ColoredConsole()
       .CreateLogger();

   BuildWebHost(args).Run();
   ```
2. And in `BuildWebHost` method:

   ```
   IWebHostBuilder hostBuilder = new WebHostBuilder()
       .UseKestrel(/* options */)
       .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
       .UseIISIntegration()
       .UseStartup<Startup>()
       .UseSerilog();
   ```

Comment: Have you checked the [readme in serilog-aspnetcore](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-aspnetcore) repo?

Comment: Make sure to read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45782021/455493) as the way logging is configured and the json structure of the config file changed with .NET Core 2. Comment if it fixes your issue, and I'll close this one

Comment: Thank you guys for the reply; I updated the question with two screenshots. No matter what I do, I can't see any additional message in the console for my new project

Comment: Pasting in your logging configuration code would help, here.

Comment: Sure, I will do it in a few hours

Comment: I edited the question with code blocks

Comment: Great - and is there any code configuring the custom logger, i.e. in Startup.cs via `ILoggerFactory`, etc.?

Comment: There's an `ILoggerFactory` interface in the custom logger, but in its own namespace, and there's a registration for that: `services.AddTransient<ILoggerFactory, ...>()`.
Maybe it's also worth mentioning that they have "hacks" to use Unity as the DI container, and I see a line like this: `unityBuilder.UnityContainer.RegisterType(typeof(Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILoggerFactory), typeof(LoggerFactory), new InjectionFactory(c => new LoggerFactory()));`
Oh and I just noticed that this line isn't present in the old project! And if I comment out this line, I will get exception

Comment: I'm sorry, ignore my last comment, I was in the middle of writing it and I accidentally pressed `ENTER`, read the next one please:

Comment: Actually, as I was writing this comment, I noticed that there's a line in the new project that wasn't present in the old one!

`unityBuilder.UnityContainer.RegisterType(typeof(Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILoggerFactory), typeof(LoggerFactory), new InjectionFactory(c => new LoggerFactory()));`

They have their own "hacks" to use Unity as the DI container, and if I comment out this line, I will see an exception regarding resolution of `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILoggerFactory` saying `The type LoggerFactory has multiple constructors of length 2. Unable to disambiguate`

Comment: And it seems that the reason for that exception is that at some point, they're trying to manually resolve `ILoggerFactory` to call `CreateLogger` to pass to another custom logger!, and that's where the resolution is failing. So, for some reason, in old `project.json` project, there was no need to have that line because it could resolve `ILoggerFactory`, but in 2.0 it can't

Comment: So, @NicholasBlumhardt do you have an idea of a proper way to inject `ILoggerFactory` in this case?

Comment: Sounds like you need to remove all of the custom logging registration, use Serilog's `UseSerilog()` to set it up, and then add back the old custom logging as a Serilog sink plugged into the Serilog logger (if you need it). Better to aim for reaching a manageable long-term solution. HTH!

Comment: Thank you for your help; I'll see what I can do. I'm not so sure if I can do much with this terrible logging implementation they have done in our company, and they insist so much on using it!